# New limits when changing to polar coordinates for calculating a double integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Calculate

$$\iint_D {1 \over {(x^2+y^2)^2}} dxdy$$

when: $$D= \{\space (x,y) \in \mathbb R ^2 \space |\space {1 \over 2} \le x \space,\space x \le y \le \sqrt 3 x\space,\space x^2+y^2 \le 1\space \}$$

I change to polars $\space x=r \cos \theta$, $\space y=r \sin \theta \space$, and I can see that ${\pi \over 4}\le \theta \le {\pi \over 3}$, but what are the limits of $r$?

Even when I draw this I can't figure what they are.

Note: I just want to understand how to find the new limits, I'll calculate the rest by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $\theta$, you need to integrate from the vertical line $x = \frac{1}{2}$ to the circle $r=1$.  The upper limit is obviously $1$.

As for the lower limit, the equation $x=\frac{1}{2}$ translated to polar coordinates becomes
$$
    r \cos\theta = \frac{1}{2} \implies r = \frac{1}{2\cos\theta} = \frac{1}{2}\sec\theta
$$
This means that
$$
    D = \left\{(r,\theta)\mid \frac{\pi}{4} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{3},\  \frac{1}{2} \sec\theta \leq r \leq 1\right\}
$$